# Format of Angular 5 functions

Tags: angular, function, return-type

I'm looking at this code which represents a class in `Angular 5`:

```
export class HeroService {

  constructor() { }

  getHeroes(): Hero[] {
    return HEROES;
  }

}
```

My question is about the method `getHeroes()`. What does the `: Hero[]` portion of the function mean?

Comment: It means the function returns and array of type Hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`: Hero[]` indicates that the function `getHeroes` is going to return an array of `Hero`.

Any typescript variable type can be identified as a return value. This is good practice as it supports the strictly typed ideology that typescript brings to Javascript.

Note though that is is actually optional, although you should always include it.

This is an example of what the generated Javacsript would be with and without the return type declaration:

**Original TS**

```
class SomeClass{
    public Hello() {
        return "Hello string";
    }

    public World(): string {
        return "World string";
    }
}
```

**Resulting JS**

```
var SomeClass= /** @class */ (function () {
    function SomeClass() {
    }
    SomeClass.prototype.Hello = function () {
        return "Hello string";
    };
    SomeClass.prototype.World = function () {
        return "World string";
    };
    return SomeClass;
}());
```

As you can see there is literally no difference in the 2 functions. The return value is purely for the `pre-compiled` environment so that it can throw errors when you try and do something like:

`var int: NotAHero[] = getHeroes();`